# Erasing from a list that you are nested iterating over

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Say you're iterating over a list using a nested for loop like this:

```
  for( list<Object>::iterator iter = list.begin() ; iter != list.end() ; ++iter )
  {
    for( list<Object>::iterator iter2 = list.begin() ; iter2 != list.end() ; ++iter2 )
    {
      if( iter != iter2 )
      {
        if( some other condition )
        { 
          iter2 = list.erase( iter2 ) ; 
          // uh oh! what about iter?
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

How can you maintain `iter`?

Comment: since `iter != iter2` your `iter` will not be affected

Comment: you can check the iterator validity rules here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[list:erase only invalidates the iterators pointing to the item being erased](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/erase/). Since `iter` is not equal to `iter2`, you should be fine.